# How to run php via cli in docksal?

Tags: php, docker, docksal

I have docksal/docker installed on MacOS and am able to do LAMP development in it without any problem.

However, I seem unable to run php via the command line.

```
-bash: php: command not found
```

If I go into a bash shell, I can run php, but I need to run it without dropping into the bash layer because the directory tree is different there.

My cli container config as is follows (via fin config show)

```
Docker Compose configuration
---------------------
services:
  cli:
    dns:
    - 75.75.75.75
    - 9.9.9.9
    environment:
      BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID: null
      BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN: null
      COMPOSER_ALLOW_XDEBUG: "1"
      COMPOSER_DEFAULT_VERSION: null
      COMPOSER_DISABLE_XDEBUG_WARN: "1"
      DOCROOT: web
      DRUSH_ALLOW_XDEBUG: "1"
      DRUSH_OPTIONS_URI: pii.docksal.site
      GIT_USER_EMAIL: Ayen1026!
      GIT_USER_NAME: root
      HOST_GID: "20"
      HOST_UID: "501"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: default
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: user
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: null
      SECRET_ACQUIA_CLI_KEY: null
      SECRET_ACQUIA_CLI_SECRET: null
      SECRET_PLATFORMSH_CLI_TOKEN: null
      SECRET_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: null
      SECRET_TERMINUS_TOKEN: null
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /.ssh-agent/proxy-socket
      VIRTUAL_HOST: pii.docksal.site
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: client_host=192.168.64.1 remote_host=192.168.64.1
      XDEBUG_ENABLED: "1"
    extends:
      file: /Users/acme/.docksal/stacks/services.yml
      service: cli
    hostname: cli
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
    image: docksal/cli:php8.1-3.2
    labels:
      io.docksal.shell: bash
      io.docksal.user: docker
    logging:
      options:
        max-file: "10"
        max-size: 1m
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: docksal_ssh_agent
      target: /.ssh-agent
      read_only: true
      volume: {}
    - type: volume
      source: cli_home
      target: /home/docker
      volume: {}
    - type: bind
      source: /tmp/.docksal/pii
      target: /tmp/.docksal/pii
      read_only: true
      bind:
        create_host_path: true
    - type: volume
      source: project_root
      target: /var/www
      volume:
        nocopy: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Drush?

```
fin drush php:cli
```

The Drush docs have some [other PHP commands](https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/php_cli/), but they're post-bootstrap.